# Python win32com: Internet Explorer COM object ? (used to work?)

Tags: python, com, winapi, automation, internet-explorer

I have this very simple program:

```
from win32com import client
ie=client.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

This used to work (I think I broke something when I re-used 'makepy.py' to try and add in constants for IE).

It still works on another machine where I haven't been so slap-dash with 'makepy.py'.

Here's what I get in an interactive Python session on the non-working machine:

```
>>> ie
>>> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Internet Controls.IWebBrowser2 instance at 0x14701432
>
>>> ie.Visible=True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 471, in
 __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

And the same on a working machine:

```
>>> from win32com import client
>>> ie=client.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
>>> ie
>>> <ComObject InternetExplorer.Application>
>>> ie.Visible=1 # This then brings up IE correctly.
```

How do I get this working again ? Or am I using the wrong way of launching IE ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Went into here:

```
Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py
```

Renamed the .py and .pyc file to .py_ and .pyc_ files :

```
85CC894D-5673-4868-9A22-9E15B7E694D3x0x1x1.pyc
```

Restarted Python: now get the Internet Explorer. phew...